# Why Window.Visibility property is not being "getted"?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Working with MVVM, I have a `MainView.xaml` and a corresponding `MainViewModel.cs`. I also have a user control, `HomeView.xaml`, as well as `HomeViewModel.cs`.

Also, I have a `TaskBarService`, singleton, being injected on both `MainViewModel.cs` and `HomeViewModel.cs`. `MainView.Window.Visibility` is bound to `TaskBarService.WindowVisibility` via a property.

On the `HomeView`, when the user clicks a button, `TaskBarService.WindowVisibility` is set to `Visibility.Hidden`, while calling `OnPropertyChanged` for that same property. But `MainView.Window.Visibility` never looks for the new value. I've set a breakpoint on the property setter and it is only triggered once, when `MainView` is instanced. What am I doing wrong?

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly IHost _host;
    public App()
    {
        _host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args = null)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .AddServices()
            .AddStores()
            .AddViewModels()
            .AddViews();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _host.Start();


        Window janela = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<MainView>();
        TaskBarController taskBarController = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<TaskBarController>();
        taskBarController.WindowVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    protected override async void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        await _host.StopAsync();
        _host.Dispose();

        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application x:Class="<mynamespace>.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<mynamespace>"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:<mynamespace>.ViewModels"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:<mynamespace>.Views">
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:HomeViewModel}">
        <views:HomeView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}"/>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**AddServices**

```
public static class AddServicesHostBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder AddServices(this IHostBuilder host)
    {
        host.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
           services.AddSingleton<TaskBarController>();

        });
        return host;
    }
}
```

**AddStores**

```
 public static class AddStoresHostBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder AddStores(this IHostBuilder host)
    {
        host.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<INavigator, Navigator>();
        });

        return host;
    }
}
```

**AddViewModels**

```
public static class AddViewModelsHostBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder AddViewModels(this IHostBuilder host)
    {
        host.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IViewModelFactory, ViewModelFactory>();

            services.AddSingleton<HomeViewModel>();
            services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();


            services.AddSingleton<CreateViewModel<HomeViewModel>>(services => () => services.GetRequiredService<HomeViewModel>());
        });
        return host;
    }
}
```

**AddViews**

```
public static class AddViewsHostBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder AddViews(this IHostBuilder host)
    {
        host.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddSingleton<MainView>(createMainView);
        });
        return host;
    }
    private static MainView createMainView(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        return new MainView(services.GetRequiredService<MainViewModel>());
    }
}
```

**ViewModelBase**

```
public delegate TViewModel CreateViewModel<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : ViewModelBase;
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

**MainView.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="<mynamespace>.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    Title="MainView" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None"
    Height="250" Width="400" Visibility="{Binding WindowVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}">
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModelAtual}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainView : Window
{
    public MainView(object dataContext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = dataContext;
    }
}
```

**HomeView.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="<mynamespace>.Views.HomeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="❌">
        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding CloseWindow}"/>
        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Navigator.cs**

```
public class Navigator : INavigator
{
    private ViewModelBase _viewModelAtual;

    public ViewModelBase ViewModelAtual
    {
        get { return _viewModelAtual; }
        set
        {
            _viewModelAtual = value;
            StateChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public event Action StateChanged;
}
```

**ViewModelFactory.cs**

```
public class ViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly CreateViewModel<HomeViewModel> _createHomeViewModelFactory;

    public ViewModelFactory(CreateViewModel<HomeViewModel> createHomeViewModelFactory)
    {
        _createHomeViewModelFactory = createHomeViewModelFactory;
    }

    public ViewModelBase CreateViewModel(TipoView tipoView)
    {
        switch (tipoView)
        {
            case TipoView.Home:
                return _createHomeViewModelFactory();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("The ViewType does not have a ViewModel.", "viewType");
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskBarController**

```
public class TaskBarController : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Visibility windowVisibility;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public Visibility WindowVisibility
    {
        get => windowVisibility;
        set
        {
            windowVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WindowVisibility));
        }
    }

    public void MinimizeToTray()
    {
        WindowVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public void MaximizeFromTray()
    {
        WindowVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

**UpdateViewModelCommand.cs**

```
public class UpdateViewModelAtualCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly INavigator _navigator;
    private readonly IViewModelFactory _viewModelFactory;

    public UpdateViewModelAtualCommand(INavigator navigator, IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory)
    {
        _navigator = navigator;
        _viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is TipoView)
        {
            TipoView tipoView = (TipoView)parameter;

            _navigator.ViewModelAtual = _viewModelFactory.CreateViewModel(tipoView);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
private readonly IViewModelFactory _viewModelFactory;
        private readonly INavigator _navigator;
        private TaskBarController _taskBarController;

        public ViewModelBase ViewModelAtual => _navigator.ViewModelAtual;
        public MainViewModel(INavigator navigator,
            IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory, TaskBarController taskBarController)
        {
            _taskBarController = taskBarController;
            _navigator = navigator;
            _viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;

            _navigator.StateChanged += _navigator_StateChanged;

            UpdateViewModelAtual = new UpdateViewModelAtualCommand(navigator, _viewModelFactory);
            UpdateViewModelAtual.Execute(TipoView.Home);

        }

        private void _navigator_StateChanged()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ViewModelAtual));
        }

        public ICommand UpdateViewModelAtual { get; set; }
        public Visibility WindowVisibility
        {
            get => _taskBarController.WindowVisibility;
            set
            {
                _taskBarController.WindowVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WindowVisibility));
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have two such properties. You set one but bind the other.

Comment: @Andy My bad, there was an extra property on the code I posted. `TaskBarVisibility` was something else, not pertaining to the current situation. I've edited the post removing the unused property.

Comment: Is `HomeViewModel` and `CloseWindowCommand` the same thing...?

Comment: No. It's just `HomeViewModel` has a standard constructor, that I thought I didn't need to explicitly show. But I've added the constructor now.

Comment: There is no generic version of `CreateMainView`.

Comment: @mm8 Both viewmodels implement `public delegate TViewModel CreateViewModel<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : ViewModelBase;`

Comment: @ASousa: Not in the code you have posted. It doesn't compile.

Comment: @mm8 I've added the full definition of my `ViewModelBase`

Comment: @ASousa: How is this related to `CreateMainView`?

Comment: You have some kind of confusion about your MainViewModel code.
In this code, you are declaring the HomeViewModel class, but a constructor is specified for the MainViewModel class.
Fix please.

Comment: Alright, that example is too messy to "fix". Should I delete this question and start over with a new and better example?

Comment: @ASousa: Yes, please provide a *minimal* reproducible sample.

Comment: @mm8 as per your suggestion, I have created a new question and flagged this one for removal.

Comment: In addition to the general problem that you should have edited this original question to fix its flaws rather than writing a new question, you don't seem to have understood the guidance at [mcve], because the code you posted in the new question is definitely _not_ the **minimal** code require to reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: @Peter I'm willing to post a actual mre, but I had asked whether I should *delete* this one and *start* a new one with a working mre, and I was told "Yes, please post a minimal reproductible sample"... I did not know what I had to do, and that's why I asked whether I should do that. So now, I've been told to edit this one instead, so I'm doing that.

Comment: You aren't comprehending my comment. You misunderstood the earlier advice from @mm8 (granted, they also failed to be precise). But that's not relevant. My comment is not relevant to _where_ you posted the code, but rather the fact that you think you posted a [mcve], when in fact you did not. Yes, you need to edit this question. But don't bother doing so unless you are willing to make the effort to write a proper [mcve] for the question.

Comment: The example I just posted can be compiled now.

Comment: It's not a question of whether it can be compiled, though that's certainly important. It's a question of whether the code example is **MINIMAL**. Please read [mcve]. Seriously. **Read it.** Also read [ask], and read the articles linked at the bottom of _that_ page, and pay very close attention to all of the valuable advice seen on all of those references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once upon a time I figured out the Window.Visibility binding, but the topic is in Russian, so I don't give a link here.
The bottom line is that any other action on Window.Visibility destroys the binding in that property.
Therefore, it is very critical how you create and display the MainWondow.
If you specified it in StartupUri, or applied the Window.Show () method to it, or specified the Visibility = ... value directly, the binding will be destroyed.

Example:

```
public class FlashingViewModel : BaseInpc
{
    private Visibility _windowVisibility;

    public Visibility WindowVisibility { get => _windowVisibility; set => Set(ref _windowVisibility, value); }

    private readonly Timer timer = new Timer();

    public FlashingViewModel()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
            WindowVisibility = 
                WindowVisibility == Visibility.Visible
                ? Visibility.Hidden
                : Visibility.Visible;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="***.MainWindow"
        ------------
        -----------
        Visibility="{Binding WindowVisibility}"
      >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:FlashingViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

```
<Application x:Class="***.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="OnStartup">
    <!--StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">-->
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow = new MainWindow();
    }
}
```

BaseInpc is my implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Alright, my `App.xaml.cs` was instancing `MainView` and calling `mainView.Show()`. Now it just instances `MainView` and since the `Visibility` is bound to the property, whose default value is `Visibility.Visible`, the window is shown. However, `MainView.Window.Visibility` still doesn't update along with `TaskBarService.WindowVisibility`

Comment: @ASousa: Your example is incomplete.

Comment: @mm8 What do you mean? What would it need to be complete?

Comment: @ASousa: _host.Services and how you set the `DataContext` and call your property...

Comment: @mm8 Sure, I'll add those - I didn't think that would be needed, as they're just standard dependency injection stuff, and I've stated `TaskBarService` is singleton.

Comment: Either you gave an incomplete code, or there are many ... ambiguities in it.
It is not clear how you set the DataContext MainWindow.
When the value of TaskBarController.WindowVisibility changes, no event is raised in the MainViewModel class.

Comment: There, I've added the pertaining information, I believe.

Comment: I already wrote above.
In the command, you change the TaskBarController.WindowVisibility.
But your binding is set to the MainViewModel.WindowVisibility property.
In this case, the property in the MainViewModel is implemented in such a way that changing it leads to a change in the property in the TaskBarController.
But changing the property in the TaskBarController doesn't raise PropertyChanged event in the MainViewModel.
For this reason, although you have changed the property in the TaskBarController in the command, the binding does not react to this change.

Comment: But I have `MainViewModel.WindowVisibility => _taskBarController.WindowVisibility`. Doesn't that expose the controller's property? Or should I set my service instance to `public`?

Comment: Alright, I've found the issue. Although having `MainViewModel.WindowVisibility => _taskBarController.WindowVisibility` does expose the property, it doesn't raise any `PropertyChanged`events... I must manually tell my view model to expect changes by listening to the service's `PropertyChanged` event and raising the view model's own `OnPropertyChanged`; Thanks.